# vim ctrl-O to jump inside the file

Tags: vim, macvim

:jumps returns a list of the jumps, but when I press < Ctrl-O> or < Ctrl-I> nothing happens. Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: what do you get if you run `:verbose map <c-o>`

Comment: It responds "n   <C-o>", but when I hit n it gives me an error saying "Pattern not found: jumplist"

Comment: No, the `n` is just an indicator for a normal-mode mapping, not the source key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you somehow re-mapped C-O to something else.

`:verbose map <c-o>` will tell you what  was mapped to.

from your comment, you said if you give command `:verbose map <c-o>`, it response `n <C-o>`. I think there should be something more than that.

```
n means Normal mode mapping, 
<C-O> means from key-bind
there should be a mapping to ?
```

you typed n, it reports "Pattern not found: jumplist". I guest your last search was `jumplist`. to verify that, you could in normal mode type "n", and see the not found pattern word. e.g. jumplist. then type `"/p` see if it was your last search.

Another thing you could try is `:nunmap <c-o>`, then press `<c-o>`, see if it jumps..

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. It responds "n  <C-O>         10zl"

Comment: @sara well, then you could unmap `<c-o>` or map your 10zl to other keys to make ctrl-o jumping work.

Comment: Oh, ok, I found it in my .vimrc. Thanks for your help. I didn't know the verbose command, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have files you have edited before. I tried it works for me.

Comment: I thought these keys were for moving around through the jumps. Anyway, even if the jumps are in the same file I am editing, these keys are not working.